# How to install Ubuntu 16.04 on external HD

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, usb, external-hdd

It appears my laptop has a failing hard disk according to SMART and Ubuntu Disk Utility.  Due to my location having the disk replaced is not easily viable however I have an external HD and a LiveCD usb stick so I am thinking of reinstalling Ubuntu on the external HD.  My concerns are whether I should reformat the laptop HD in a way that Ubuntu does not recognise it I am concerned about inadvertently booting without the external connected as I understand this could prevent both disks from booting - I no longer need to access the internal HD if I can install on external - I have a copy of all data.  I cannot disconnect or disable the internal since this would mean completely stripping down the laptop as the internal is not easily accessible. - thankyou

Comment: Is the computer booting in UEFI mode or BIOS (legacy alias CSM) mode? The advice will depend on your answer.

Comment: OK I think I can only check that by checking bios and I am in the middle of big backup at the moment so cant reboot but i believe it is UEFI - thanks

Comment: Installing Ubuntu in UEFI mode works best, if you remove the internal drive. Otherwise the bootloader will be installed into the internal drive, and you don't want that with the failing drive, and you cannot remove it easily. The obvious alternative is to change to boot in BIOS mode. It it an option for you? Both Ubuntu and Windows 10 can be installed in BIOS mode. Or would it be possible to 'turn off' the internal drive via an UEFI-BIOS menu?

Comment: You can check with `test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo bios`

Comment: I cannot turn off or remove internal drive.  But BIOS mode is aceptable if I know how. Are their any advantages or disadvantages and how does that protect against bootloader on internal - thanks again - sorry just saw your other comment - I will try when backup finished

Comment: When installing in BIOS mode you can select *'Something else'* at the partitioning page, and select partitions manually. *At the bottom of the page you should select the drive where to install the bootloader*. Select the head of the drive (not a partition), so for example `/dev/sdb` if it is the second drive (I would guess that the internal drive is  `/dev/sda` as long as it is recognized.)

Comment: OK command you gave gives response - efi so how can I install in BIOS mode or do I need to regenerate LiveCD

Comment: I think the only way is to enter the UEFI-BIOS menu system of your computer. You do that at the very beginning of the boot. There is a hotkey, sometimes F2 or F10, but it can be 'any key', and it is different between different brand names and models of computers. Search the internet to find it for your computer. Then you have to browse the menus to find where to change to BIOS mode. The menus are also different between computers. - If you tell us the brand name and model, maybe someone knows and can help.

Comment: Think I found it - installing now but very slow :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58713/discussion-between-sudodus-and-kerry).

Comment: @sudosus - i am on chat :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK finally sorted this by following

set bios options to boot bios instead of efi and boot from usb memory stick

boot from live cd on memory stick

use gparted to partition drive as ext4 saving 4gb free space to create swap

run installer and when asked where to install choose 'something else'

highlight new partition and click 'change'

set as ext4, mount to / then format

then highlight swap partition and set as swap

set the bootloader to the devx that is the external drive

click 'install now'

all went well but at the end the boot loader could not be installed so I chose the option to finish install without bootloader

when finished i booted again from memory stick and reinstalled grub on the external drive - all working fine now

did have some issues with .deb packages i copied over but simply downloaded again

also some strange issues with permissions but easily solved by searching askubuntu

also permissions seem to change when copying depending which drive you boot from.

Currently I set usb drive as boot device every time as I am not sure what problems I will create if I boot from internal drive by mistake

Hope this helps somebody

Thanks to Sudodus for the pointers you gave me that helped me find the full solution for me

Comment: Congratulations :-)